# C# library is not automatically updated. Compile succeeded but auto-complete failed

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I have a library LibA referenced by a console application program AppB. LibA and AppB are not in the same solution. I revised LibA by adding a new static method MethodC to ClassD and recompile LibA. Then I tried to use MethodC in AppB. Auto-complete in the editor failed, that is after I type "ClassD.", I cannot find MethodC in the auto-complete list. Well, no problem, despite this I still continue to typed "MethodC" and compile. Somehow it succeeded! but with a red line under the code in the editor indicating something wrong in the code. But how come compile succeeded. And I open the object browser, LibA is still the old version. Even after I removed the reference and re-referenced LibA, I got the same result.

How can I use the new methods in LibA? What is the correct steps? Thanks.

Comment: Start cleaning the solution for AppB, then be sure to reference the correct assembly (pay attention to how you compiled LibA, Release vs Debug x86 vs AnyCpu, any difference here and your compiled LibA.DLL ends in a different folder and your AppB could still reference a version in a different folder.)

Comment: Problem solved by restarting VS. I think the reason should be that VS got stuck(what the hell! we bought the professional version). Thanks so much for all of your answers. Actually all the configurations were properly set up including build path, Release Vs Debug x86 Vs AnyCpu(in fact I use Release and AnyCpu). And I found out a wired thing that when I delete LibA.XML in LibA\bin\Release\, it appears shortly automatically! No idea if it is the problem of my PC or VS.

Comment: By default, if everything is all good, after I rebuilt LibA, I should be able to use the new method MethodC immediately in AppB.cs without doing anything. Actually it behaviors as expected after I restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons it may not be working as it should.

1.You have referenced a compiled DLL as a dependency from one particular disk path but now compiling to a different place. This may happen if you start playing with AnyCpu, x86, x64 targets. They normally change output from default to target platform specific.

2. The second reason is that you forgot to tick "Build" checkbox in build configuration for the DLL, which is no longer updating. Check both Release and Debug modes, as it can be set in one, but be cleared in another.

The good starting point is to check to what folder your dependency compiles to. In order to do that you can do a right click on the project, click "Properties", then select "Build" tab, and look for "Target Folder" property.